# QGIS layout models: problem from 3.28 to 3.22

Tags: qgis, print-composer, layouts

I have different layout models, that I build in 3.22. I can use them in the new LTR (3.28).

But the problem is if I open the project in 3.22 (some computers in my office are still in 3.22), all the text blocs lose the police size and the police font.

Does the last LTR introduces a difference in the layout, so that a previous version can't use it? Cause if I have a 3.22 project, QGIS 3.16 can use the layout without any problem?!?

Answer (score 2):

This is probably answered in the [changelog for version 3.30](https://qgis.org/en/site/forusers/visualchangelog330/index.html):

> Importantly, support for backward compatibility of Symbol Styling has been removed for QGIS 3.16, providing significant optimizations to the project file structure, but limiting the capability of older releases of QGIS for rendering symbologies developed with later releases. This change has been ported to the release of 3.28 LTR as well.

It's difficult to say if the changes break print layout objects, but I wouldn't be surprised that this is linked in some way and on a practical level, general retrocompatibility shouldn't be expected in light of these changes.

Comment: But it should not be remove from 3.28 down to 3.22? Or do I read wrong?

Comment: This is something that the devs will have to answer so it would be better suited for the issue tracker on Github. The real world behavior for you though is that layout object properties aren't retrocompatible from 3.28 to 3.22. Occam's razor explanation is that the styling changes affected other parts of the program and this applies up to 3.22 LTR.

Comment: Was there anything ever came of this? I am having the same issue with composer template fonts being broken from upgrade to 3.28